# Check the Picture box value is null or not

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a visual C# windows form application using Visual Studio IDE.

My problem is how to check if the user has selected an image or not.

I roughly check the Image like a String, Integer objects but it does not work

```
if(myPictureBox.Image == NULL){
    //The Image is Null
}
```

Comment: please try being specific

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I have edit this question under community guideline. Please upvote to release me. I was banned to ask questions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a check like this

```
bool isNullOrEmpty = myPictureBox == null || myPictureBox.Image == null;
```

Or you can create your own extension method

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this PictureBox pb)
{
    return pb == null || pb.Image == null;
}
```

Comment: Hi David Pilkington,

I change some changes in your code its' know work

  bool isNullOrEmpty = (myPictureBox.Image == null);

Comment: @NifrasIsmail that just checks if it is empty not if it is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if(myPictureBox.ImageLocation == NULL){
//The Image is Null
```

}